# C# get object from asyncron task

Tags: c#, task

i just startet thread programming in c#. And I realy dont know if this is the right community to ask questions like that. If not, im sorry.

I have two functions, start() and status(). In start() I create an new task like:

```
start() {
   for each(dir => ListOfAllDirs) {
       new Task(() => { yr.LoadAllFiles(dir); }).Start();
   }
 }
```

so I have about 200 parallel Tasks Running with this code:

```
class yr
{
    List<Values> rv = new List<Values>();
    public List<Values> LoadAllFiles(string dir)
    {
       [...DoStuff...]
       rv.Add(...);
       rv.Add(...);
       rv.Add(...);
    }

}
```

So I dont know how to access the > 200 running Threads to get the data, before they're finished. I'm looking for sth. like:

```
status(dir) {
    int count = GetTaskByName[dir].rv.Count; (????)
    Console.WriteLine("Dir " + dir + "->" + count + "files checked");
}
```

And the final Output:

```
Dir AA -> 19 files checkes
Dir AB -> 12 files checkes
Dir BB -> 49 files checkes
Dir AA -> 29 files checkes
```

So to be clear: 200 dirs, 200 tasks, everything is running asyncron. How do I access a specific Task / get Data from the running Task.

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: How can I access objects from running asycron tasks?

Comment: This question is really vague. Read it yourself top to bottom. Could you understand it if it wasn't you? I don't even know what to ask specifically right now. You have to fix this somehow.

Comment: I'm sorry, is it better to now?

Comment: Much better, answers are now possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently, you need to take 200 directories and compute a result for each of them. PLINQ makes that exceptionally easy:

```
var results =
ListOfAllDirs
.AsParallel()
.Select(dir => new { dir, result = yr.LoadAllFiles(dir) })
.ToList();
```

And there's your list of directories plus the computation result.

You can do it manually with tasks as well. In that case you probably want a sequence like this:

1. Create all tasks and store them
2. Use Task.WaitAll to wait for completion
3. Use Task.Result on each task to get the result

Comment: Ok, thank you. This helps a lot. Is is possible to grab the interim results of non complete tasks. So I can check every 2 seconds and get results like: "Up to now 33 Files found in Dir AA", [..] "Up to now 44 Files found in Dir AA"

Comment: I'd probably make the tasks themselves report progress. You can make them update the UI when some progress has happened. Alternatively, you can iterate through the list of tasks and check their `Status` to see whether they are completed or not.

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for something like this?

```
var task = Task<List<values>>.Run((() => { return yr.LoadAllFiles(dir);}));
List<values> result = task.Result;
```

If it has a result type, you access the result on the task. That waits for the task to complete and gets the result.